# HTML Email - Can't restrict width

Tags: html, css, email, width, cell

I'm charged with 'rebranding' our IT department communications. I wanted to do our email notifications in pure HTML / CSS to ensure it's portability.

Below is the code, which looks exactly how I want it to in Outlook, however as soon as content is added to the main  the words wont wrap correctly and if any content goes further than about 90% of the main content window, the other table components start to stretch!

I've tried all sorts of combinations of 'word-wrap' and 'overflow' at all levels in the table but I can't seem to have it.

My end goal is to have the entire table fixed width, with any long format information expanding down.

```
<table style="width: 550px; border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Arial; color: #282828;">
  <tr style="border: 1px solid gray;">
        <td style="height: 75px; width: 80px; text-align: center; font-size: 60px; font-weight: bold; color: White; background : #007F0E;border-bottom: 1px solid gray;">i</td>
        <td style="height: 75px; padding-left: 15px; font-size: 22px;font-weight: bold;border-bottom: 1px solid gray; color: #282828;">Information</td>
        <td style="height: 75px; padding-right: 15px; text-align: right; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid gray;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><div style="height: 36; text-align: right; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; color: #0088CE">company name</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><div style="height: 36;text-align: right; font-size: 22px;font-weight: bold; color: #282828;">Information Systems</div></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 20px; background : #007F0E;border-bottom: 1px solid gray;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="99" style="font-family: Arial; height : 300px; padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px;padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">This is the main TD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="99" style="background: #EEEEEE;font-size: 12px; text-align: center; height : 20px; border-Top: 1px solid gray;"><b>IT Helpdesk </b><b style="color: #0088CE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><b>Ext : </b> <a href="">XXXX</a><b style="color: #0088CE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><b>Email : </b> <a href="mailto:">Link</a><b style="color: #0088CE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><b> Portal : </b> <a href="">Link</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, this one minor issue is taking me way to long to overcome!

Good:

[image: Good]

Bad (this is just random, wordwrapped text):

[image: Bad]

Comment: Have you tried changing colspan="99" to colspan="3"?

Comment: The other thing you could try is removing colspan entirely and using another nested table for your first column instead.

Comment: I sent it to my hotmail account and viewed it the online outlook and it looks fine.

Comment: colspan="3" does nothing different, I had it at 99 as I was playing with a couple different layouts and didn't want to have to change it every time, it was a tip from some website, not sure if it's valid or not.

It def appears to be a COLSPAN issue however. I'm looking into using more nested tables to accommodate for the different column numbers instead of spanning it.

I'l also clean the code up as there is a lot of extra stuff while I've been testing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was definitely related to the use of COLSPAN.

Instead I replaced the 'heading' piece with a nested table and that resolved the issue.

The specific code I used:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 550px; border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Arial; color: #282828;">
  <tr>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 75px;text-align: center; font-size: 60px; font-weight: bold; color: White; width: 80px; background : #007F0E;border-bottom: 1px solid gray;">i</td>
            <td style="height: 75px;width: 200px; padding-left: 15px; font-size: 22px;font-weight: bold;border-bottom: 1px solid gray; color: #282828;">Information</td>
            <td style="height: 75px;padding-right: 15px; text-align: right; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid gray;">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; color: #0088CE">company name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: right; font-size: 22px;font-weight: bold; color: #282828;">Information Systems</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20px; background : #007F0E;border-bottom: 1px solid gray;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family: Arial; height : 300px; padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px;padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px; vertical-align: top; text-align: left;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: #EEEEEE;font-size: 12px; text-align: center; height : 20px; border-Top: 1px solid gray;"><b>IT Helpdesk </b><b style="color: #0088CE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><b>Ext : </b> <a href="tel:+">XXXX</a><b style="color: #0088CE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><b>Email : </b> <a href="mailto:">Link</a><b style="color: #0088CE">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><b> Portal : </b> <a href="">Link</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It is certainly painful but unfortunately working with in the constraints of not only Outlook, but also our helpdesk application which doesn't allow direct HTML code. The only way is to directly copy a table in (which is why I've tried to contain it all in a single table!)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your html:

- you don't need a nested table for the right header section. Just the `<div>` portions are enough.
- you should set widths for the 'Information' and 'Company name' `<td>` cells to prevent arbitrary wrapping.
- your `colspan` value should be `colspan="4"`, not `colspan="99"`

Anyways, to solve your problem you can add `style="table-layout: fixed;"` to your main table element, to allow yourself to set a more predictable table layout.

https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Comment: I'll have to clean the code and re-enter it, a lot of the stuff you have pointed out are things I've put in to try and work around this width issue.

My first thought was I had messed up the header so I was trying to restrict that.

It def looks like an issue with COLSPAN though.

I've also used style="table-layout: fixed;" with no noticeable difference